# Does every injective morphism of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules have a left inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, inverse-function

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra and let $M$ and $N$ be (not necessarily finite dimensional) $\mathfrak{g}$-modules over a field $k$. Let $f: M\to N$ be an injective $k$-linear map of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules.

We know that $f$ has a left inverse in the category of $k$-vector spaces but does it have a left inverse in the category of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules? Thank you for a proof or a simple counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

By the [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) this is true iff the short exact sequence

$$0 \to M \to N \to N/M \to 0$$

splits. If this is true for every $M, N$ then the category of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules must be semisimple, which I think never happens unless $\mathfrak{g} = 0$ (not even if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple; that only guarantees semisimplicity of finite-dimensional representations, and maybe that even requires hypotheses on the field?).

In any case it's easy to give a counterexample: let $\mathfrak{g} = k$ be the one-dimensional abelian Lie algebra, so that a $\mathfrak{g}$-module is equivalently a $k[x]$-module ($k[x]$ is the universal enveloping algebra). Then, for example, the $2$-dimensional representation given by the Jordan block

$$x \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$$

is a nontrivial extension of the trivial representation by itself, hence corresponds to a short exact sequence $0 \to k \to V \to k \to 0$ which does not split.

**Edit:** Here's a proof of the general claim.

> **Claim:** If the category of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules is semisimple then $\mathfrak{g} = 0$.

*Proof.* Since the category of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules is equivalently the category of $U(\mathfrak{g})$-modules, we want to show that the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple iff $\mathfrak{g} = 0$. The [PBW theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem) implies that $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is an integral domain; by the classification of semisimple algebras it follows that $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple iff it is a division algebra over $k$. But $U(\mathfrak{g})$ admits an augmentation homomorphism to $k$ given by sending every element of $\mathfrak{g}$ to zero; hence if it's a division algebra over $k$ it must be $k$ itself. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice answer. Thank you for the counterexample! To prove that the short exact sequence $0\to M\to N\to N/M\to 0$, we do not have to assume that $N/M$ can be identified with a subspace of N, right? I am asking because if M and N are infinite dimensional Lie algebras, then N/M might not be a subspace of $N$. In the special case of an infinite dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and an infinite dimensional Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{n}$, does the short exact sequence $0\to\mathfrak{n}\to\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}\to0$ always split? What fails if not?

Comment: @Flavius: no, we don't have to assume that; you can take a look at the statement of the splitting lemma for more clarification. In what sense do you want that short exact sequence to split? As vector spaces? As Lie algebras?

Comment: @ Qiaochu, Thank you for the confirmation. Yes, I looked at the statement of the splitting lemma. I want the short exact sequence of $\mathfrak{n}$-modules $0\to\mathfrak{n}\to\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}\to$ to split in the category of $\mathfrak{n}$-modules or equivalently in the category of $U(\mathfrak{n})$-modules ($U(\mathfrak{n})$ is the universal enveloping algebra). I think that in the category of vector spaces, it always splits.

Comment: @Flavius: I don't expect that sequence to split in $\mathfrak{n}$-modules in general but I don't know a counterexample off the top of my head.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However, if it would split, would be the isomorphism $\mathfrak{g}\cong\mathfrak{n}\oplus\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}$ be automatically $\mathfrak{n}$-equivariant?

Comment: Yes, that's what it would mean for it to split as a sequence of $\mathfrak{n}$-modules.

Comment: Right. Thanks. Where is the principal difficulty actually with the splitting of the short exact sequence in the category of $\mathfrak{n}$-modules-in general, we do not know if the quotient $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}$ is stable with respect to the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{n}$? Is that the problem? If $\mathfrak{n}$ is assumed to be a finite dimensional subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, is it then easier to determine if $0\to\mathfrak{n}\to\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}\to0$ splits?

Comment: The quotient is always stable with respect to the action of $\mathfrak{n}$, that follows from the fact that $\mathfrak{n}$ is stable with respect to the action of $\mathfrak{n}$. We just have no reason to expect such sequences to split if the action of $\mathfrak{n}$ isn't semisimple and generally it won't be.

Comment: Wait! But $\mathfrak{g}$ splits in a direct 
sum $\mathfrak{n}\oplus\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}$ as a complex vector space. So, we have a splitting in which each summand is stable with respect to the action of $\mathfrak{n}$.Isn't that precisely the splitting in $\mathfrak{n}$-modules we are looking for?

Comment: If you only split as vector spaces you've lost any compatibility with the $\mathfrak{n}$-action.

Comment: Okay. Understood. But if $\mathfrak{n}$ is semisimple, then its action is semisimple. Then, the short exact sequence always splits?

Comment: That would only work if $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: So, every isomorphism of $\mathfrak{n}$-modules $\mathfrak{g}\cong\mathfrak{n}\oplus\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}$ establishes a subspace in $\mathfrak{g}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}$ as a complex vector space and which is also invariant with respect to the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{n}$ on $\mathfrak{g}$. There might be many such $\mathfrak{n}$-invariant subspaces but there might be none. In the second case the short exact sequence does not split. That is the picture here, right?

Comment: There's one additional condition. Splittings correspond to isomorphisms of $\mathfrak{n}$-modules $\mathfrak{g} \cong \mathfrak{n} \oplus \mathfrak{g}/\mathbb{n}$ which are compatible with the natural inclusion $\mathfrak{n} \to \mathfrak{g}$ and with the natural quotient map $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{n}$. There may be such isomorphisms which are not compatible in this way.

Comment: But such an isomorphism, which is not compatible with the natural inclusion and the natural projection, should nevertheless fit in a short split-exact sequence of $\mathfrak{n}$-modules, no?